# How to uses refs in React Native with Hooks?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, ref

I'm developing a React Native app with Hooks. (No Classes). When we use classes, we can create a ref to a child component like this.

```
<Child ref={component => this.childComponent = component} />
```

But, how to do this when we use Hooks?

I want something like this.

```
export default function Child() {
  const foo = () => {
    //do something
  }

  return(
    //something
  )
}


export default function Parent() {
  const myFunc = () => {
    ref.foo();
  }

  return(
    <Child ref={.........} />  //This is what I want to know how to do?
  )
}
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to define refs with hooks, you need to use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook. And in order to apply ref to functional components you need to use [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) and [`useImperativeHandle hook`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)

```
function Child(props, ref) {
  const foo = () => {
    //do something
  }

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
     foo
  }));

  return(
    //something
  )
}

export default React.forwardRef(Child)


export default function Parent() {
  const childRef = useRef(null)
  const myFunc = () => {
    childRef.current.foo();
  }

  return(
    <Child ref={childRef} />  
  )
}
```